Error ID 11 - The KDC encountered duplicate names while processing a Kerberos authentication request
The KDC encountered duplicate names while processing a Kerberos authentication request. The duplicate name is cifs/SERVER-CDC (of type DS_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME). This may result in authentication failures or downgrades to NTLM. In order to prevent this from occurring remove the duplicate entries for cifs/SERVER-CDC in Active Directory.

Could you do a LDAP search (servicePrincipalName=*SERVER-CDC*) against your Active Directory and report back the results?

That means there are multiple principals with the Service Principal Name cifs/SERVER-CDC.
You can use the following command to search for the duplicate SPN:
SetSPN -x -f cifs/SERVER-CDC.

i tried this command but not working, is there any other option.

You’re going to need to provide more information than “not working” if you want help.  What error messages are you getting?

The KDC encountered duplicate names while processing a Kerberos authentication request. The duplicate name is cifs/SERVER-CDC (of type DS_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME). This may result in authentication failures or downgrades to NTLM. In order to prevent this from occurring remove the duplicate entries for cifs/SERVER-CDC in Active Directory. --------same errors showing in event viewer. I just replace server name.

@sparemail: and the recommendation to search for the duplicate name using AD Users and Computers?

@GregAskew checked each user and hostname but no duplicate found. is it possible 2 users has same name ? but showing only 1

Why not use the built-in search?
